# How to add GPUMLib in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, gpu

I'm trying to use the c++ machine learning library GPUMLib downloaded at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpumlib/
How can I add this project in Visual studio in order to use it?

Comment: It's a library, not a project. Check the `examples/` folder, which *does* have some actual VS projects.

Answer (score 1):

I build it with cmake. I put the source floder "GPUMLib" and cmake.exe in the same floder. In CMD ues commod 'cmake GPUMLib' , if you are fortunatrly enough you will get a GPUMLib Microsoft Visual Studio solution file. Open the sulotion file use VS,you can build it.
One problem may arise, the ReductionKernels project can not load correctly, just remove the ** Fliters Files.